# Failed to install neural_render_pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch, torchvision

I try to install neural_render_pytorch by command "pip install neural_renderer_pytorch".
But have a big error and i do not understand it.
Error message:

```
    Running setup.py install for neural-renderer-pytorch ... error
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: /home/danyilzozulia/PycharmProjects/test/venv/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-bhf3anci/neural-renderer-pytorch_8cf9e80a49224bd798a82d088a984e58/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-bhf3anci/neural-renderer-pytorch_8cf9e80a49224bd798a82d088a984e58/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-ilhc49xm/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/danyilzozulia/PycharmProjects/test/venv/include/site/python3.8/neural-renderer-pytorch
     cwd: /tmp/pip-install-bhf3anci/neural-renderer-pytorch_8cf9e80a49224bd798a82d088a984e58/
Complete output (209 lines):
running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/neural_renderer
copying neural_renderer/load_obj.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/neural_renderer
copying neural_renderer/projection.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/neural_renderer
copying neural_renderer/look.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/neural_renderer
copying neural_renderer/mesh.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/neural_renderer
copying neural_renderer/vertices_to_faces.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/neural_renderer
copying neural_renderer/perspective.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/neural_renderer
copying neural_renderer/look_at.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/neural_renderer
copying neural_renderer/renderer.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/neural_renderer
copying neural_renderer/get_points_from_angles.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/neural_renderer
copying neural_renderer/rasterize.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/neural_renderer
copying neural_renderer/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/neural_renderer
copying neural_renderer/lighting.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/neural_renderer
copying neural_renderer/save_obj.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/neural_renderer
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/neural_renderer/cuda
copying neural_renderer/cuda/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/neural_renderer/cuda
running build_ext
building 'neural_renderer.cuda.load_textures' extension
creating /tmp/pip-install-bhf3anci/neural-renderer-pytorch_8cf9e80a49224bd798a82d088a984e58/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8
creating /tmp/pip-install-bhf3anci/neural-renderer-pytorch_8cf9e80a49224bd798a82d088a984e58/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/neural_renderer
creating /tmp/pip-install-bhf3anci/neural-renderer-pytorch_8cf9e80a49224bd798a82d088a984e58/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/neural_renderer/cuda
Emitting ninja build file /tmp/pip-install-bhf3anci/neural-renderer-pytorch_8cf9e80a49224bd798a82d088a984e58/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/build.ninja...
Compiling objects...
Allowing ninja to set a default number of workers... (overridable by setting the environment variable MAX_JOBS=N)
[1/2] /usr/bin/nvcc --generate-dependencies-with-compile --dependency-output /tmp/pip-install-bhf3anci/neural-renderer-pytorch_8cf9e80a49224bd798a82d088a984e58/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/neural_renderer/cuda/load_textures_cuda_kernel.o.d -I/home/danyilzozulia/PycharmProjects/test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include -I/home/danyilzozulia/PycharmProjects/test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include -I/home/danyilzozulia/PycharmProjects/test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/TH -I/home/danyilzozulia/PycharmProjects/test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/THC -I/home/danyilzozulia/PycharmProjects/test/venv/include -I/usr/include/python3.8 -c -c /tmp/pip-install-bhf3anci/neural-renderer-pytorch_8cf9e80a49224bd798a82d088a984e58/neural_renderer/cuda/load_textures_cuda_kernel.cu -o /tmp/pip-install-bhf3anci/neural-renderer-pytorch_8cf9e80a49224bd798a82d088a984e58/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/neural_renderer/cuda/load_textures_cuda_kernel.o -D__CUDA_NO_HALF_OPERATORS__ -D__CUDA_NO_HALF_CONVERSIONS__ -D__CUDA_NO_BFLOAT16_CONVERSIONS__ -D__CUDA_NO_HALF2_OPERATORS__ --expt-relaxed-constexpr --compiler-options ''"'"'-fPIC'"'"'' -DTORCH_API_INCLUDE_EXTENSION_H '-DPYBIND11_COMPILER_TYPE="_gcc"' '-DPYBIND11_STDLIB="_libstdcpp"' '-DPYBIND11_BUILD_ABI="_cxxabi1011"' -DTORCH_EXTENSION_NAME=load_textures -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 -gencode=arch=compute_61,code=compute_61 -gencode=arch=compute_61,code=sm_61 -std=c++14
FAILED: /tmp/pip-install-bhf3anci/neural-renderer-pytorch_8cf9e80a49224bd798a82d088a984e58/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/neural_renderer/cuda/load_textures_cuda_kernel.o
/usr/bin/nvcc --generate-dependencies-with-compile --dependency-output /tmp/pip-install-bhf3anci/neural-renderer-pytorch_8cf9e80a49224bd798a82d088a984e58/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/neural_renderer/cuda/load_textures_cuda_kernel.o.d -I/home/danyilzozulia/PycharmProjects/test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include -I/home/danyilzozulia/PycharmProjects/test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include -I/home/danyilzozulia/PycharmProjects/test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/TH -I/home/danyilzozulia/PycharmProjects/test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/THC -I/home/danyilzozulia/PycharmProjects/test/venv/include -I/usr/include/python3.8 -c -c /tmp/pip-install-bhf3anci/neural-renderer-pytorch_8cf9e80a49224bd798a82d088a984e58/neural_renderer/cuda/load_textures_cuda_kernel.cu -o /tmp/pip-install-bhf3anci/neural-renderer-pytorch_8cf9e80a49224bd798a82d088a984e58/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/neural_renderer/cuda/load_textures_cuda_kernel.o -D__CUDA_NO_HALF_OPERATORS__ -D__CUDA_NO_HALF_CONVERSIONS__ -D__CUDA_NO_BFLOAT16_CONVERSIONS__ -D__CUDA_NO_HALF2_OPERATORS__ --expt-relaxed-constexpr --compiler-options ''"'"'-fPIC'"'"'' -DTORCH_API_INCLUDE_EXTENSION_H '-DPYBIND11_COMPILER_TYPE="_gcc"' '-DPYBIND11_STDLIB="_libstdcpp"' '-DPYBIND11_BUILD_ABI="_cxxabi1011"' -DTORCH_EXTENSION_NAME=load_textures -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 -gencode=arch=compute_61,code=compute_61 -gencode=arch=compute_61,code=sm_61 -std=c++14
nvcc fatal   : Unknown option '-generate-dependencies-with-compile'
[2/2] c++ -MMD -MF /tmp/pip-install-bhf3anci/neural-renderer-pytorch_8cf9e80a49224bd798a82d088a984e58/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/neural_renderer/cuda/load_textures_cuda.o.d -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/home/danyilzozulia/PycharmProjects/test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include -I/home/danyilzozulia/PycharmProjects/test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include -I/home/danyilzozulia/PycharmProjects/test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/TH -I/home/danyilzozulia/PycharmProjects/test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/THC -I/home/danyilzozulia/PycharmProjects/test/venv/include -I/usr/include/python3.8 -c -c /tmp/pip-install-bhf3anci/neural-renderer-pytorch_8cf9e80a49224bd798a82d088a984e58/neural_renderer/cuda/load_textures_cuda.cpp -o /tmp/pip-install-bhf3anci/neural-renderer-pytorch_8cf9e80a49224bd798a82d088a984e58/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/neural_renderer/cuda/load_textures_cuda.o -DTORCH_API_INCLUDE_EXTENSION_H '-DPYBIND11_COMPILER_TYPE="_gcc"' '-DPYBIND11_STDLIB="_libstdcpp"' '-DPYBIND11_BUILD_ABI="_cxxabi1011"' -DTORCH_EXTENSION_NAME=load_textures -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 -std=c++14
FAILED: /tmp/pip-install-bhf3anci/neural-renderer-pytorch_8cf9e80a49224bd798a82d088a984e58/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/neural_renderer/cuda/load_textures_cuda.o
c++ -MMD -MF /tmp/pip-install-bhf3anci/neural-renderer-pytorch_8cf9e80a49224bd798a82d088a984e58/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/neural_renderer/cuda/load_textures_cuda.o.d -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/home/danyilzozulia/PycharmProjects/test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include -I/home/danyilzozulia/PycharmProjects/test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include -I/home/danyilzozulia/PycharmProjects/test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/TH -I/home/danyilzozulia/PycharmProjects/test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/THC -I/home/danyilzozulia/PycharmProjects/test/venv/include -I/usr/include/python3.8 -c -c /tmp/pip-install-bhf3anci/neural-renderer-pytorch_8cf9e80a49224bd798a82d088a984e58/neural_renderer/cuda/load_textures_cuda.cpp -o /tmp/pip-install-bhf3anci/neural-renderer-pytorch_8cf9e80a49224bd798a82d088a984e58/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/neural_renderer/cuda/load_textures_cuda.o -DTORCH_API_INCLUDE_EXTENSION_H '-DPYBIND11_COMPILER_TYPE="_gcc"' '-DPYBIND11_STDLIB="_libstdcpp"' '-DPYBIND11_BUILD_ABI="_cxxabi1011"' -DTORCH_EXTENSION_NAME=load_textures -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 -std=c++14
In file included from /home/danyilzozulia/PycharmProjects/test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/ATen/Parallel.h:140,
                 from /home/danyilzozulia/PycharmProjects/test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/utils.h:3,
                 from /home/danyilzozulia/PycharmProjects/test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/nn/cloneable.h:5,
                 from /home/danyilzozulia/PycharmProjects/test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/nn.h:3,
                 from /home/danyilzozulia/PycharmProjects/test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/all.h:13,
                 from /home/danyilzozulia/PycharmProjects/test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/torch.h:3,
                 from /tmp/pip-install-bhf3anci/neural-renderer-pytorch_8cf9e80a49224bd798a82d088a984e58/neural_renderer/cuda/load_textures_cuda.cpp:1:
/home/danyilzozulia/PycharmProjects/test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/ATen/ParallelOpenMP.h:83: warning: ignoring #pragma omp parallel [-Wunknown-pragmas]
   83 | #pragma omp parallel for if ((end - begin) >= grain_size)
      |
/tmp/pip-install-bhf3anci/neural-renderer-pytorch_8cf9e80a49224bd798a82d088a984e58/neural_renderer/cuda/load_textures_cuda.cpp: In function ‘at::Tensor load_textures(at::Tensor, at::Tensor, at::Tensor, at::Tensor, int, int)’:
/tmp/pip-install-bhf3anci/neural-renderer-pytorch_8cf9e80a49224bd798a82d088a984e58/neural_renderer/cuda/load_textures_cuda.cpp:15:39: warning: ‘at::DeprecatedTypeProperties& at::Tensor::type() const’ is deprecated: Tensor.type() is deprecated. Instead use Tensor.options(), which in many cases (e.g. in a constructor) is a drop-in replacement. If you were using data from type(), that is now available from Tensor itself, so instead of tensor.type().scalar_type(), use tensor.scalar_type() instead and instead of tensor.type().backend() use tensor.device(). [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   15 | #define CHECK_CUDA(x) AT_CHECK(x.type().is_cuda(), #x " must be a CUDA tensor")
      |                                       ^
/tmp/pip-install-bhf3anci/neural-renderer-pytorch_8cf9e80a49224bd798a82d088a984e58/neural_renderer/cuda/load_textures_cuda.cpp:17:24: note: in expansion of macro ‘CHECK_CUDA’
   17 | #define CHECK_INPUT(x) CHECK_CUDA(x); CHECK_CONTIGUOUS(x)
      |                        ^~~~~~~~~~
/tmp/pip-install-bhf3anci/neural-renderer-pytorch_8cf9e80a49224bd798a82d088a984e58/neural_renderer/cuda/load_textures_cuda.cpp:28:5: note: in expansion of macro ‘CHECK_INPUT’
   28 |     CHECK_INPUT(image);
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /home/danyilzozulia/PycharmProjects/test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/ATen/Tensor.h:3,
                 from /home/danyilzozulia/PycharmProjects/test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/ATen/Context.h:4,
                 from /home/danyilzozulia/PycharmProjects/test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/ATen/ATen.h:9,
                 from /home/danyilzozulia/PycharmProjects/test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/types.h:3,
                 from /home/danyilzozulia/PycharmProjects/test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/data/dataloader_options.h:4,
                 from /home/danyilzozulia/PycharmProjects/test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/data/dataloader/base.h:3,
                 from /home/danyilzozulia/PycharmProjects/test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/data/dataloader/stateful.h:3,
                 from /home/danyilzozulia/PycharmProjects/test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/data/dataloader.h:3,
                 from /home/danyilzozulia/PycharmProjects/test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/data.h:3,
                 from /home/danyilzozulia/PycharmProjects/test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/all.h:8,
                 from /home/danyilzozulia/PycharmProjects/test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/torch.h:3,
                 from /tmp/pip-install-bhf3anci/neural-renderer-pytorch_8cf9e80a49224bd798a82d088a984e58/neural_renderer/cuda/load_textures_cuda.cpp:1:
/home/danyilzozulia/PycharmProjects/test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/ATen/core/TensorBody.h:303:30: note: declared here
  303 |   DeprecatedTypeProperties & type() const {
      |                              ^~~~
/tmp/pip-install-bhf3anci/neural-renderer-pytorch_8cf9e80a49224bd798a82d088a984e58/neural_renderer/cuda/load_textures_cuda.cpp:15:23: error: ‘AT_CHECK’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘DCHECK’?
   15 | #define CHECK_CUDA(x) AT_CHECK(x.type().is_cuda(), #x " must be a CUDA tensor")
      |                       ^~~~~~~~
/tmp/pip-install-bhf3anci/neural-renderer-pytorch_8cf9e80a49224bd798a82d088a984e58/neural_renderer/cuda/load_textures_cuda.cpp:15:23: note: in definition of macro ‘CHECK_CUDA’
   15 | #define CHECK_CUDA(x) AT_CHECK(x.type().is_cuda(), #x " must be a CUDA tensor")
      |                       ^~~~~~~~
/tmp/pip-install-bhf3anci/neural-renderer-pytorch_8cf9e80a49224bd798a82d088a984e58/neural_renderer/cuda/load_textures_cuda.cpp:28:5: note: in expansion of macro ‘CHECK_INPUT’
   28 |     CHECK_INPUT(image);
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~
/tmp/pip-install-bhf3anci/neural-renderer-pytorch_8cf9e80a49224bd798a82d088a984e58/neural_renderer/cuda/load_textures_cuda.cpp:15:39: warning: ‘at::DeprecatedTypeProperties& at::Tensor::type() const’ is deprecated: Tensor.type() is deprecated. Instead use Tensor.options(), which in many cases (e.g. in a constructor) is a drop-in replacement. If you were using data from type(), that is now available from Tensor itself, so instead of tensor.type().scalar_type(), use tensor.scalar_type() instead and instead of tensor.type().backend() use tensor.device(). [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   15 | #define CHECK_CUDA(x) AT_CHECK(x.type().is_cuda(), #x " must be a CUDA tensor")
      |                                       ^
/tmp/pip-install-bhf3anci/neural-renderer-pytorch_8cf9e80a49224bd798a82d088a984e58/neural_renderer/cuda/load_textures_cuda.cpp:17:24: note: in expansion of macro ‘CHECK_CUDA’
   17 | #define CHECK_INPUT(x) CHECK_CUDA(x); CHECK_CONTIGUOUS(x)
      |                        ^~~~~~~~~~
/tmp/pip-install-bhf3anci/neural-renderer-pytorch_8cf9e80a49224bd798a82d088a984e58/neural_renderer/cuda/load_textures_cuda.cpp:29:5: note: in expansion of macro ‘CHECK_INPUT’
   29 |     CHECK_INPUT(faces);
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /home/danyilzozulia/PycharmProjects/test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/ATen/Tensor.h:3,
                 from /home/danyilzozulia/PycharmProjects/test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/ATen/Context.h:4,
                 from /home/danyilzozulia/PycharmProjects/test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/ATen/ATen.h:9,
                 from /home/danyilzozulia/PycharmProjects/test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/types.h:3,
                 from /home/danyilzozulia/PycharmProjects/test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/data/dataloader_options.h:4,
                 from /home/danyilzozulia/PycharmProjects/test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/data/dataloader/base.h:3,
                 from /home/danyilzozulia/PycharmProjects/test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/data/dataloader/stateful.h:3,
                 from /home/danyilzozulia/PycharmProjects/test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/data/dataloader.h:3,
                 from /home/danyilzozulia/PycharmProjects/test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/data.h:3,
                 from /home/danyilzozulia/PycharmProjects/test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/all.h:8,
                 from /home/danyilzozulia/PycharmProjects/test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/torch.h:3,
                 from /tmp/pip-install-bhf3anci/neural-renderer-pytorch_8cf9e80a49224bd798a82d088a984e58/neural_renderer/cuda/load_textures_cuda.cpp:1:
/home/danyilzozulia/PycharmProjects/test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/ATen/core/TensorBody.h:303:30: note: declared here
  303 |   DeprecatedTypeProperties & type() const {
      |                              ^~~~
/tmp/pip-install-bhf3anci/neural-renderer-pytorch_8cf9e80a49224bd798a82d088a984e58/neural_renderer/cuda/load_textures_cuda.cpp:15:39: warning: ‘at::DeprecatedTypeProperties& at::Tensor::type() const’ is deprecated: Tensor.type() is deprecated. Instead use Tensor.options(), which in many cases (e.g. in a constructor) is a drop-in replacement. If you were using data from type(), that is now available from Tensor itself, so instead of tensor.type().scalar_type(), use tensor.scalar_type() instead and instead of tensor.type().backend() use tensor.device(). [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   15 | #define CHECK_CUDA(x) AT_CHECK(x.type().is_cuda(), #x " must be a CUDA tensor")
      |                                       ^
/tmp/pip-install-bhf3anci/neural-renderer-pytorch_8cf9e80a49224bd798a82d088a984e58/neural_renderer/cuda/load_textures_cuda.cpp:17:24: note: in expansion of macro ‘CHECK_CUDA’
   17 | #define CHECK_INPUT(x) CHECK_CUDA(x); CHECK_CONTIGUOUS(x)
      |                        ^~~~~~~~~~
/tmp/pip-install-bhf3anci/neural-renderer-pytorch_8cf9e80a49224bd798a82d088a984e58/neural_renderer/cuda/load_textures_cuda.cpp:30:5: note: in expansion of macro ‘CHECK_INPUT’
   30 |     CHECK_INPUT(is_update);
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /home/danyilzozulia/PycharmProjects/test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/ATen/Tensor.h:3,
                 from /home/danyilzozulia/PycharmProjects/test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/ATen/Context.h:4,
                 from /home/danyilzozulia/PycharmProjects/test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/ATen/ATen.h:9,
                 from /home/danyilzozulia/PycharmProjects/test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/types.h:3,
                 from /home/danyilzozulia/PycharmProjects/test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/data/dataloader_options.h:4,
                 from /home/danyilzozulia/PycharmProjects/test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/data/dataloader/base.h:3,
                 from /home/danyilzozulia/PycharmProjects/test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/data/dataloader/stateful.h:3,
                 from /home/danyilzozulia/PycharmProjects/test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/data/dataloader.h:3,
                 from /home/danyilzozulia/PycharmProjects/test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/data.h:3,
                 from /home/danyilzozulia/PycharmProjects/test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/all.h:8,
                 from /home/danyilzozulia/PycharmProjects/test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/torch.h:3,
                 from /tmp/pip-install-bhf3anci/neural-renderer-pytorch_8cf9e80a49224bd798a82d088a984e58/neural_renderer/cuda/load_textures_cuda.cpp:1:
/home/danyilzozulia/PycharmProjects/test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/ATen/core/TensorBody.h:303:30: note: declared here
  303 |   DeprecatedTypeProperties & type() const {
      |                              ^~~~
/tmp/pip-install-bhf3anci/neural-renderer-pytorch_8cf9e80a49224bd798a82d088a984e58/neural_renderer/cuda/load_textures_cuda.cpp:15:39: warning: ‘at::DeprecatedTypeProperties& at::Tensor::type() const’ is deprecated: Tensor.type() is deprecated. Instead use Tensor.options(), which in many cases (e.g. in a constructor) is a drop-in replacement. If you were using data from type(), that is now available from Tensor itself, so instead of tensor.type().scalar_type(), use tensor.scalar_type() instead and instead of tensor.type().backend() use tensor.device(). [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   15 | #define CHECK_CUDA(x) AT_CHECK(x.type().is_cuda(), #x " must be a CUDA tensor")
      |                                       ^
/tmp/pip-install-bhf3anci/neural-renderer-pytorch_8cf9e80a49224bd798a82d088a984e58/neural_renderer/cuda/load_textures_cuda.cpp:17:24: note: in expansion of macro ‘CHECK_CUDA’
   17 | #define CHECK_INPUT(x) CHECK_CUDA(x); CHECK_CONTIGUOUS(x)
      |                        ^~~~~~~~~~
/tmp/pip-install-bhf3anci/neural-renderer-pytorch_8cf9e80a49224bd798a82d088a984e58/neural_renderer/cuda/load_textures_cuda.cpp:31:5: note: in expansion of macro ‘CHECK_INPUT’
   31 |     CHECK_INPUT(textures);
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /home/danyilzozulia/PycharmProjects/test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/ATen/Tensor.h:3,
                 from /home/danyilzozulia/PycharmProjects/test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/ATen/Context.h:4,
                 from /home/danyilzozulia/PycharmProjects/test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/ATen/ATen.h:9,
                 from /home/danyilzozulia/PycharmProjects/test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/types.h:3,
                 from /home/danyilzozulia/PycharmProjects/test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/data/dataloader_options.h:4,
                 from /home/danyilzozulia/PycharmProjects/test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/data/dataloader/base.h:3,
                 from /home/danyilzozulia/PycharmProjects/test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/data/dataloader/stateful.h:3,
                 from /home/danyilzozulia/PycharmProjects/test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/data/dataloader.h:3,
                 from /home/danyilzozulia/PycharmProjects/test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/data.h:3,
                 from /home/danyilzozulia/PycharmProjects/test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/all.h:8,
                 from /home/danyilzozulia/PycharmProjects/test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/torch.h:3,
                 from /tmp/pip-install-bhf3anci/neural-renderer-pytorch_8cf9e80a49224bd798a82d088a984e58/neural_renderer/cuda/load_textures_cuda.cpp:1:
/home/danyilzozulia/PycharmProjects/test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/ATen/core/TensorBody.h:303:30: note: declared here
  303 |   DeprecatedTypeProperties & type() const {
      |                              ^~~~
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/danyilzozulia/PycharmProjects/test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/cpp_extension.py", line 1667, in _run_ninja_build
    subprocess.run(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 512, in run
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['ninja', '-v']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip-install-bhf3anci/neural-renderer-pytorch_8cf9e80a49224bd798a82d088a984e58/setup.py", line 29, in <module>
    setup(
  File "/home/danyilzozulia/PycharmProjects/test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 153, in setup
    return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/home/danyilzozulia/PycharmProjects/test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py", line 61, in run
    return orig.install.run(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/command/install.py", line 589, in run
    self.run_command('build')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/command/build.py", line 135, in run
    self.run_command(cmd_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/home/danyilzozulia/PycharmProjects/test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/command/build_ext.py", line 79, in run
    _build_ext.run(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 340, in run
    self.build_extensions()
  File "/home/danyilzozulia/PycharmProjects/test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/cpp_extension.py", line 708, in build_extensions
    build_ext.build_extensions(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 449, in build_extensions
    self._build_extensions_serial()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 474, in _build_extensions_serial
    self.build_extension(ext)
  File "/home/danyilzozulia/PycharmProjects/test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/command/build_ext.py", line 196, in build_extension
    _build_ext.build_extension(self, ext)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 528, in build_extension
    objects = self.compiler.compile(sources,
  File "/home/danyilzozulia/PycharmProjects/test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/cpp_extension.py", line 529, in unix_wrap_ninja_compile
    _write_ninja_file_and_compile_objects(
  File "/home/danyilzozulia/PycharmProjects/test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/cpp_extension.py", line 1354, in _write_ninja_file_and_compile_objects
    _run_ninja_build(
  File "/home/danyilzozulia/PycharmProjects/test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/cpp_extension.py", line 1683, in _run_ninja_build
    raise RuntimeError(message) from e
RuntimeError: Error compiling objects for extension
```

I am new in CUDA and pytorch so can you help, please, resolve this problem.
I`m using CUDA V10.1, pytorch V1.8.0, putorch3d 0.3.0.

Answer (score 1):

I just found the answer elsewhere. The issue is caused by the compilation resource of the project not compatible with the pytorch version you installed. You can either downgrade your pytorch version OR change all `AT_CHECK` in the source code into `TORCH_CHECK`. The latter worked for me. Wish you good luck!